# How do I add to an ICollection property when iterating object type?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, icollection

I have need to add to an `ICollection<string>` property of a class of which I have an `IEnumerable` of. Here is a complete program which illustrates the problem:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace CollectionAddingTest
{
    public class OppDocumentServiceResult
    {
        public OppDocumentServiceResult()
        {
            this.Reasons = new List<string>();
        }

        public Document Document { get; set; }

        public bool CanBeCompleted
        {
            get
            {
                return !Reasons.Any();
            }
        }

        public ICollection<string> Reasons { get; private set; }
    }

    public class Document
    {
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var docnames = new List<string>(new[] {"test", "test2"});

            var oppDocResult = docnames
                .Select(docName
                        => new OppDocumentServiceResult
                               {
                                   Document = new Document { Name = docName }
                               });

            foreach (var result in oppDocResult)
            {
                result.Document.Name = "works?";
                result.Reasons.Add("does not stick");
                result.Reasons.Add("still does not stick");
            }

            foreach (var result in oppDocResult)
            {
                // doesn't write "works?"
                Console.WriteLine(result.Document.Name);

                foreach (var reason in result.Reasons)
                {
                    // doesn't even get here
                    Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", reason);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect that each OppDocumentServiceResult would have its referenced `Document.Name` 
property set to *works?* and each OppDocumentServiceResult should have two reasons added to it. However, neither is happening.

What is special about the Reasons property that I cannot add things to it?

Comment: It should work absolutely fine. Please provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet modified the above to be a bit more complete. Clear as mud?

Comment: Not really - it's still not a short but complete program which we can use to work out exactly what's going on...

Comment: You are iterating each instance which, in turn, as a fresh Reasons List created; In your example do you want one Reason for each instance?

Comment: @JonSkeet edited something from a Console App created from the original question. I am having the same behaviour (and indeed I get an exception in the writeline)

Comment: @JonSkeet added a complete program. Still having the issue. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed like this, converting to List instead of keeping the IEnumerable:

```
var oppDocResult = docnames
        .Where(docName => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(docName))
        .Select(docName
            => new OppDocumentServiceResult
            {
                Document = docName
            }).ToList();
```

I can only guess (this is a shot in the dark really!) that the reason behind this is that in an IEnumerable the elements are like "proxies" of the real elements? basically the Enumerable defined by the Linq query is like a "promise" to get all the data, so everytime you iterate you get back the original items? That does not explain why a normal property still sticks...

So, the fix is there but the explanation I am afraid is not... not from me at least :(

Comment: Thanks for the "shot in the dark." I've posted a complete program which illustrates the issue. Maybe we'll get there. :)

Comment: The reason is that each time you `foreach` over `oppDocResults` you get a sequence with entirely new `OppDocuemntServiceResults` rather than getting the same `OppDocuemntServiceResults` that the previous iteration used.  By `ToList`ing the results you ensure that iterating over the list repeatedly is always returning the same objects.  Since you're now getting the same objects you are able to see the changes in made in previous iterations.

Comment: I've added an explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is your initial `Select` you are instantiating new `OppDocumentServiceResult` objects. Add a `ToList` and you should be good to go:

```
var oppDocResult = docnames
    .Select(docName
            => new OppDocumentServiceResult
                   {
                       Document = new Document { Name = docName }
                   }).ToList();
```

As [Servy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1159478/servy) pointed out I should have added a bit more detail to my answer, but thankfully [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604382/how-do-i-add-to-an-icollection-property-when-iterating-object-type/10605123#comment13739263_10605016) he left on [Tallmaris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10605016/61654) takes care of that. In his answer Jon Skeet further expands on the reason, but what it boils down to "is that oppDocResult is the result of a LINQ query, using deferred execution."

Comment: This should solve the problem, but it's probably worth explaining *why* it solves the problem.

Comment: @Servy added a bit of an explanation, but linked to your comment and Jon Skeet's answer for more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `oppDocResult` is the result of a LINQ query, using deferred execution.

In other words, every time you iterate over it, the query executes and *new* `OppDocumentServiceResult` objects are created. If you put diagnostics in the `OppDocumentServiceResult` constructor, you'll see that.

So the `OppDocumentServiceResult` objects you're iterating at the end are different ones to the ones you've added the reasons to.

Now if you add a `ToList()` call, then that *materializes* the query into a "plain" collection (a `List<OppDocumentServiceResult>`). Each time you iterate over that list, it will return references to the same objects - so if you add reasons the first time you iterate over them, then you print out the reasons when you iterate over them again, you'll get the results you're looking for.

See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx) (among many search results for "LINQ deferred execution") for more details.

Answer (score 1):

`ForEach()` is defined against only `List<T>` you will **not** be able to use it to for an `ICollection<T>`.

You have to options:

```
((List<string>) Reasons).ForEach(...)
```

Or

```
Reasons.ToList().ForEach(...)
```

---

Yet, **my preferred approach**

I would define this extension which can help automating this for you without wasting resources:

```
public static class ICollectionExtensions
{
    public static void ForEach(this ICollection<T> collection, Action<T> action)
    {
        var list = collection as List<T>;
        if(list==null)
            collection.ToList().ForEach(action);
        else
            list.ForEach(action);
    }
}
```

Now I can use `ForEach()` against `ICollection<T>`.

Comment: I agree. What I was indicating was that using a  ToList().Foreach on the IEnumerable<OppDocumentServiceResult> was not working when adding to the underlying `OppDocumentServiceResult.Reasons` property. I would have had a compile time error.

Comment: @RussClark yes, I got your point before you updated your post.

Comment: but what you are suggesting is still at the property level. I am interested in modifying the Reasons collection for each `OppDocumentServiceResult` in an IEnumerable.

Comment: @RussClark you can use the same code against `IEnumerable<T>` too. Just define such an extension.

Comment: cool I will add it to my IEnumerable and ICollection Extension methods project.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code inside your class

```
public List<string> Reasons { get; private set; }
```

Comment: I had already tried this, but just in case tried it again. Does not make a difference.